# Pass input value to ajax get Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am fairly new to Laravel and ajax in general, what I am trying to implement is to pass the value of an input field through an ajax get request.
My request looks like this:

```
function getInfo() {

        $.ajax({
            url: "info",
            dataType: "json"
        }).success(function(data){
            $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(data));
        }).fail(function(){alert('Unable to fetch data!');;
        });
    }
    $('#infoSubmit').click(getInfo);
```

I have setup a route for my function in laravel that works like this
`public/info/Variable` <--

When I add a variable after info/
I get the data for that variable (e.g profile name)

I need to pass this variable from an inputfield to ajax request to something like this:
`url: "info/+$inputfieldVariable"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
url: "info",
```

TO:

```
url: "info/" + $('input-field-selector').val(),
```

Not sure about the correctness of your JS code: Shouldn't you be using `done` instead of `success`?

Comment: forgot to remove it , i didn't had "fail" before it. I would revise it and use done instead

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
function getInfo() {

    var myFieldsValue = {};
    var $inputs = $("#myForm :input");
    $inputs.each(function() {
        myFieldsValue[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: "info",
        dataType: "json",
        data: myFieldsValue,
        type: "GET" // Even if its the default value... looks clearer
        success: function(data){
            $('#result').append(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Unable to fetch data!');
        }
    });

    return false;
}
$('#infoSubmit').click(getInfo);
```

Untested but should be something like that